# Unable to put a high resolution image inside an inline divs with 33.3333% width

Tags: html, css

I've created 3 inline divs that take 33.333% of their parent width and now I'm trying to put an images inside those divs. Sadly, if I put an image that exceeds the divs 33.333% width, the image goes out of the container. I'm trying to make it so that the image takes full width of parent container but I'm not having luck.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.gallery-element {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <section>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='.responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='.responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='.responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the first two images get cut off?

Comment: No, I need them to get scaled down so they can get inside the div.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Maybe attach a screenshot of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dots on responsive class.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.gallery-element {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <section>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the img width and height properties to 100% like this
img {
   width: 100%
   height: 100%
}

Comment: Why would that work? The image already has a width of 100% and height of auto. Changing the height won't work.

Comment: Plus the OP might not want to change all images on the page. That is why the OP is using a class on the image and styling that class.